# 取得したいデータが存在しない場合でもループ処理を止めずに次のループに移行する方法が知りたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

**環境**

ruby 2.7.2
rails 6.1
macOS

**前提**

ポートフォリオ作成のため、現在自作アプリを実装しております。
その中で、DBに必要なデータを保存するため、Rubyのnokogiriでスクレイピングを行なっています。

**エラー内容**

スクレイピングで取得したデータを繰り返し処理でDBに保存している途中、下記のエラーでループが中断、、

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `inner_text' for nil:NilClass
```

**解決したいこと**

ループ処理時、取得したいデータが存在しない場合でもループを止めず、次のループに移行する方法が知りたいです。

**試したこと**

データ取得先のサイトを確認した所、アイテムによって取得したいデータが表示されていないページも含まれており、本来値が入るはずだった変数に **nil** が入ってしまっているのが原因だと分かりました。
そのため、繰り返し処理の制御構造の`next`を使用することで解決できそうだと感じたのですが、どのように記述すればいいのか分からず、時間だけが溶けている状態です。

詳しい方がいましたら是非アドバイスいただけると幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

**該当するソースコード**

`db/schema.rb`

```
  create_table "spots", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "time"
    t.string "location"
    t.text "feature"
    t.string "image"
    t.string "url"
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.integer "area_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["area_id"], name: "index_spots_on_area_id"
  end
```

`app/models/scraping.rb`

```
class Scraping < ApplicationRecord
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'nokogiri'

  def self.spot_scrape
    base_url = 'https://loconavi.jp/'
    features_url = 'features/hananomeisho'
    url = "#{base_url}#{features_url}"

    20.times do |i|
      html = URI.open(url).read
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

      flower_href = doc.css('.flower')[i]["href"]
      next_url = "#{base_url}#{flower_href}"

      3.times do |i|
        html = URI.open(next_url).read
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
        # href属性値の取得(相対URL)。また、_[i]_はtimesメソッドの変数で、繰り返すことに1づつ数値が増えていく
        href = doc.css('.flower-spot')[i]["href"]
        # 相対URLから絶対URLを作成
        link_url = "#{base_url}#{href}"

        html = URI.open(link_url).read
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

        doc.css('.main-left-layout').each do | node |
          sleep 1
          # DBに取得したデータを保存
          Spot.create!(
            name: node.at_css('.block').inner_text,
            time: node.css('.spot-info > .t-cell')[1].inner_text,
            location: node.css('.spot-info > .t-row > .t-cell')[1].inner_text,
            feature: node.at_css('.text').inner_text,
            image: node.at_css('img').attribute('src'),
            url: node.at_css('#information p a')["href"]
          )
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

事前にnilかどうかチェックして、nilならnextする・・・という対応はいかがでしょうか？

```
doc.css('.main-left-layout').each do | node |
  sleep 1
  
  # データが取得できなかった場合は次のループに行く
  if node.at_css('.block') == nil \
    || node.css('.spot-info > .t-cell')[1] == nil \
    || node.css('.spot-info > .t-row > .t-cell')[1] == nil \
    || node.at_css('.text') == nil then
    next
  end

  # DBに取得したデータを保存
  Spot.create!(
    name: node.at_css('.block').inner_text,
    time: node.css('.spot-info > .t-cell')[1].inner_text,
    location: node.css('.spot-info > .t-row > .t-cell')[1].inner_text,
    feature: node.at_css('.text').inner_text,
    image: node.at_css('img').attribute('src'),
    url: node.at_css('#information p a')["href"]
  )
end
```